# Example of a function f: X -> Y that is continuous but not uniformly continuous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-distribution

Give an example of a function $f: X \to Y$ between metric spaces which is
continuous but not uniformly continuous, and explain why it is not uniformly
continuous.

My intuition was $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ given by $f(x) = x^2$. I think I was able to show that $f$ is continuous, but I was having trouble proving $f$ was not uniformly continuous

Comment: First, $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,1]$, since $[0,1]$ is compact, the problem would be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One of my favorite facts from single variable calculus is: if $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. So to find a non-uniformly continuous function, look for a function which is continuous but has an unbounded derivative.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Importantly, that gives a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for such an example.  It's common for a beginning student to use that line of thinking to fallaciously conclude that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring you are correct, of course. I probably should have included that caveat in my original comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show non-uniform continuity, you will have to have an unbounded domain. This is because $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ being continuous implies $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Modifying your example, $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

Suppose that $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous, then for $\epsilon = 1$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|x^2 - y^2|<1$.

Looking at the graph of $f$ we guess that $x = R$ is a large value. We take $y = R + \frac{\delta}{2}$ so that $|x-y| < \delta$.

Then,
$$1 >|f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2 - y^2| = |R^2 - (R+\frac{\delta}{2})^2| = |R\delta + \frac{\delta^2}{4}|$$.

But clearly, if we take $R$ big enough this value will be greater than 1. Hence, we have a contradiction and $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you! Will my original proof for continuity still work with the range change?